# Passing KeyboardMaestro's variable to Python script

Tags: python, keyboard-maestro

I need to create a variable with some values, and give the value to the python script one liner (`python -c "..."`) to process the variable, and get it back into the same or other variables.

How can I do that with Keyboard Maestro?

Comment: See http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/scripting.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable from KeyboardMaestro can be accessed with `os.environ['KMVAR_...']`; %Variable% is accessed as `os.environ['KMVAR_Variable']`. For the output, if you use "Execute text script", you can also control how the output from the Python interpreter would be directed.

[image]